# create DOM elements with data value from a javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a site where some basic information is outpout in a javscript. I don't have access to the server side of things - and I wonder if I could use jQuery/Vanilla JS to create a DOM element with the value from that script?

The script looks like this:

```
var retailerData = {
    "del": {
        "zip": "",
        "city": ""
    },
    "user": {
        "country": "Denmark",
        "phone": "0000",
        "nbrOrders": 0,
        "name": "John doe",
        "salesPerson": "Frederik Jensen",
        "customerNo": "5464564564",
        "email": "Johndoe@test.dk"
    },
    "order": {
        "shippingSum": 0.0,
        "orderno": "",
        "voucher": "",
        "currency": "",
        "orderVat": 0.0,
        "orderSum": 0.0,
        "items": []
    }
}
```

Comment: You could, but what kind of output are you hoping to create? It's easy enough to create DOM elements, but you need to know what you want to create first

Comment: What kind of dom element would you want to make? You could simply do `document.createElement('div')`, add any data to the element(s) and append it to the DOM.

Comment: I would do a li element with an a element for the data value. I know how to create the DOM elements - I don't know how to fetch the data value from the script though

Comment: `retailerData.del.zip` or `retailerData.user.country`, for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Small Example:

```
var retailerData = {"del":{"zip":"","city":""},"user":{"country":"Denmark","phone":"0000","nbrOrders":0,"name":"John doe","salesPerson":"Frederik Jensen","customerNo":"5464564564","email":"Johndoe@test.dk"},"order":{"shippingSum":0.0,"orderno":"","voucher":"","currency":"","orderVat":0.0,"orderSum":0.0,"items":[]}}

var mainDiv = document.createElement("DIV");        
var text1 = document.createTextNode("User Details");  
var countryDiv = document.createElement("DIV");
var text2 = document.createTextNode("Country:");  
var text3 = document.createTextNode(retailerData.user.country);  

countryDiv.appendChild(text2)
countryDiv.appendChild(text3)
mainDiv.appendChild(text1);  
mainDiv.appendChild(countryDiv);
document.body.appendChild(mainDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating DOM-elements is pretty straight forward, it is just very explicit and will take some getting used to.

In its most basic use you need three methods:

- `createElement`: creates an element (e.g. `<div>`)
- `createTextNode`: creates text content for use in elements
- `appendChild`:  add a DOM-Node (such as an element or text) to another node

Creating new elements is always a `document` operation (oversimplification: the `document` is the HTML-tree of a webpage). So you always use `document.create*`, while the actual appending of those elements is done through the elements that should contain those newly created elements.

Now that I've mentioned these native DOM methods, lets put them to use and create an unordered list containing all user information.

```js
var retailerData = {
    "del": {
        "zip": "",
        "city": ""
    },
    "user": {
        "country": "Denmark",
        "phone": "0000",
        "nbrOrders": 0,
        "name": "John doe",
        "salesPerson": "Frederik Jensen",
        "customerNo": "5464564564",
        "email": "Johndoe@test.dk"
    },
    "order": {
        "shippingSum": 0.0,
        "orderno": "",
        "voucher": "",
        "currency": "",
        "orderVat": 0.0,
        "orderSum": 0.0,
        "items": []
    }
}

//  create an <ul> element and add it to the <body>
var ul = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('ul')),
    key, li;

for (key in retailerData.user) {
  //  create a <li> element and add it to the <ul>
  li = ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));

  //  create a <span>, which is added to the <li> and immediately put text
  //  into it (appendChild returns the appended child), this practice is
  //  known as 'chaining'
  li.appendChild(document.createElement('span'))
    .appendChild(document.createTextNode(key));

  //  now add the value to the <li>, it will end up after the <span> we 
  //  created above
  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(retailerData.user[key]));
}
```

```css
li span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 8em;
  font-style: italic;
}
```

```
var ul = document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('ul')),
    key, li;

for (key in retailerData.user) {
  li = ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li'));

  li.appendChild(document.createElement('span'))
    .appendChild(document.createTextNode(key));

  li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(retailerData.user[key]));
}
```

The above snippet as [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/foozle/r1n7d0pm/)

In jQuery, the syntax is more convenient (this is one of the reasons it has become so popular)

```
var $ul = $('body').append('<ul>');

$.each(retailerData.user, function(key, value) {
    $ul.append('<li><span>' + key + '</span>' + value + '</li>');
});
```

A [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/foozle/o8q5qofg/) demonstrating jQuery.